# HLSL: Which DDX DDY are expected for TextureCube.SampleGrad()

Tags: directx, hlsl

I am wondering which DDX DDY values the SampleGrad() function expects for a TextureCube object.
I know that it's the change in UV coordinates for 2D textures. So I thought, it would be the change in the direction in this case. However, this does not seem to be the case.

I get different results if I try to use the Sample function vs. SampleGrad:

---

Sample:

```
// calculate reflected ray
float3 reflRay = reflect(-viewDir, normal);
// reflection map lookup
return reflectionMap.Sample(linearSampler, reflRay);
```

[image: correct]

---

SampleGrad:

```
// calculate reflected ray
float3 reflRay = reflect(-viewDir, normal);
// reflection map lookup
float3 dxr = ddx(reflRay);
float3 dyr = ddy(reflRay);
return reflectionMap.SampleGrad(linearSampler, reflRay, dxr, dyr);
```

[image: wrong]

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know which values for DDX and DDY are required, but if found an acceptable workaround that computes the level of detail for my gradients. Unfortunately, the quality of this solution is not as good as a real Sample function with anisotropic filtering.

In case anyone needs it:
The computation is described in: https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/archive/D3D11_3_FunctionalSpec.htm#LODCalculation

My HLSL implementation:

```cpp
// calculate reflected ray
float3 reflRay = reflect(-viewDir, normal);
// reflection map lookup
float3 dxr = ddx(reflRay);
float3 dyr = ddy(reflRay);
// cubemap size for lod computation
float reflWidth, reflHeight;
reflectionMap.GetDimensions(reflWidth, reflHeight);
// calculate lod based on raydiffs
float lod = calcLod(getCubeDiff(reflRay, dxr).xy * reflWidth, getCubeDiff(reflRay, dyr).xy * reflHeight);
return reflectionMap.SampleLevel(linearSampler, reflRay, lod).rgb;
```

Helper functions:

```cpp
float pow2(float x) {
    return x * x;
}

// calculates texture coordinates [-1, 1] for the view direction (xy values must be divided by axisMajorValue for proper [-1, 1] range).else
// z coordinate is the faceId
float3 getCubeCoord(float3 viewDir, out float axisMajorValue)
{
    // according to dx spec: https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/archive/D3D11_3_FunctionalSpec.htm#PointSampling
    // Choose the largest magnitude component of the input vector. Call this magnitude of this value AxisMajor. In the case of a tie, the following precedence should occur: Z, Y, X. 
    int axisMajor = 0;
    int axisFlip = 0;
    axisMajorValue = 0.0;
    [unroll] for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if (abs(viewDir[i]) >= axisMajorValue)
        {
            axisMajor = i;
            axisFlip = viewDir[i] < 0.0f ? 1 : 0;
            axisMajorValue = abs(viewDir[i]);
        }
    }

    int faceId = axisMajor * 2 + axisFlip;

    // Select and mirror the minor axes as defined by the TextureCube coordinate space. Call this new 2d coordinate Position.

    int axisMinor1 = axisMajor == 0 ? 2 : 0; // first coord is x or z
    int axisMinor2 = 3 - axisMajor - axisMinor1;
    // Project the coordinate onto the cube by dividing the components Position by AxisMajor. 
    //float u = viewDir[axisMinor1] / axisMajorValue;
    //float v = -viewDir[axisMinor2] / axisMajorValue;
    // don't project for getCubeDiff function!
    float u = viewDir[axisMinor1];
    float v = -viewDir[axisMinor2];

    switch (faceId)
    {
        case 0:
        case 5:
            u *= -1.0f;
            break;
        case 2:
            v *= -1.0f;
            break;
    }

    return float3(u, v, float(faceId));
}

float3 getCubeDiff(float3 ray, float3 diff)
{
    // from: https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/archive/D3D11_3_FunctionalSpec.htm#LODCalculation
    // Using TC, determine which component is of the largest magnitude, as when calculating the texel location. If any of the components are equivalent, precedence is as follows: Z, Y, X. The absolute value of this will be referred to as AxisMajor. 
    // select and mirror the minor axes of TC as defined by the TextureCube coordinate space to generate TC'.uv 
    float axisMajor;
    float3 tuv = getCubeCoord(ray, axisMajor);
    // select and mirror the minor axes of the partial derivative vectors as defined by the TextureCube coordinate space, generating 2 new partial derivative vectors dX'.uv & dY'.uv. 
    float derivateMajor;
    float3 duv = getCubeCoord(diff, derivateMajor);
    // Calculate 2 new dX and dY vectors for future calculations as follows:
    // dX.uv = (AxisMajor*dX'.uv - TC'.uv*DerivativeMajorX)/(AxisMajor*AxisMajor)
    float3 res;
    res.z = 0.0;
    res.xy = (axisMajor * duv.xy - tuv.xy * derivateMajor) / (axisMajor * axisMajor);

    return res * 0.5;
}

// dx, dy in pixel coordinates
float calcLod(float2 dX, float2 dY)
{
    // from: https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/archive/D3D11_3_FunctionalSpec.htm#LODCalculation
    float A = pow2(dX.y) + pow2(dY.y);
    float B = -2.0 * (dX.x * dX.y + dY.x * dY.y);
    float C = pow2(dX.x) + pow2(dY.x);
    float F = pow2(dX.x * dY.y - dY.x * dX.y);

    float p = A - C;
    float q = A + C;
    float t = sqrt(pow2(p) + pow2(B));

    float lengthX = sqrt(abs(F * (t+p) / ( t * (q+t))) + abs(F * (t-p) / ( t * (q+t))));
    float lengthY = sqrt(abs(F * (t-p) / ( t * (q-t))) + abs(F * (t+p) / ( t * (q-t))));

    return log2(max(lengthX,lengthY));
}
```